# Using Jquery to set value in dropdown and triggering change event in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I am building a form on Cognito Forms and although the platform is amazing, there are still a few features that I need that isn't available (yet).

One of those features is a language choice option for the user (not the builder). For the builder, there's an option to set the language to something other than English which automatically changes the placeholder text and validation error messages to the chosen language. I wanted to allow the user to have the same experience.

Currently, I only need the Spanish language option and so, I coded a modal window popup with two buttons. English (id="EN") and Spanish (id="SP").

When either one of those buttons are clicked, a value is selected from a drop-down list on the form (English or Spanish). It works and the values change on screen, but...

The problem lies when the 'Next' button is clicked- In order to test that the form was taking my jquery-coded selection, I included a simple calculation field to show the value of the dropdown from the previous page. I keep getting a null value as if nothing was selected even though I can clearly see the value in the dropdown field.

One other thing to note is that once I click on the dropdown field, and even without making a selection, the calculation field on the next page will update properly.

I embedded the form onto a temporary page and it can be seen [here](https://www.broadscopepartners.com/sandbox)

The following is the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).load(function () {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
});

$(document).on("click", "#EN", function(event){
    $("#c-0-5 option[value=English]").attr("selected","selected");
});

$(document).on("click", "#SP", function(event){
    $("#c-0-5 option[value=Spanish]").attr("selected","selected");
});

</script>

<!-- Modal HTML -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Language</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Please select a language:</p>
        <p>Por favor, seleccione su idioma:</p>
        <br>
        <center><button id="EN" name="EN" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">English</button>
        <button id="SP" name="SP" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Español</button></center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

FYI, I have also tried $("#EN").val("English").change(); as well.

[image]

Comment: Questions like this are in a bit of a gray area in terms of whether they are on-topic.  We usually focus on questions related to the use of the Cognito Forms web interface (though I realize there are other exceptions to this on [Webapps.SE]).  This question is more geared to [SO], honestly, since it's more of a jQuery issue than anything.

Comment: @jonsca I certainly agree that there is an overlap with cognito forms and jQuery, but based on my code, it's pretty clear that I've done what I could given how most dropdown list events are handled. Given that cognito forms has a different way of handling events, I thought it'd be best to address this matter here. I actually do have the same question posted on stack overflow. So, it's not necessarily a jQuery issue anymore and it's a much easier question for someone with intimate knowledge of cognito forms' event handling structure.